# Pushing into array Selenium IDE 2019

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm trying to populate an array automatically.

These stepes just returns an array containing "foo". The "bar"-string I'm trying to push into it doesnt seem to be included.

```
execute script | return ["foo"] | testVar
execute script | ${testVar}.push("bar") |
echo | ${testVar}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this approach to update an array in Selenium IDE

```
execute script | return ['foo'] | testVar
execute script | return [${testVar}, 'bar'] | testVar
echo | ${testVar}
```

**UPDATE**
Previous solution is not correct because of wrong value will be stored in the variable *testVar*. It will be array of array of arrays. So here is the correct one:

```
execute script | return ['foo'] | testVar
execute script | tmp = ${testVar}; tmp.push('bar'); return tmp; | testVar
echo | ${testVar}
```

Comment: I don't know why I don't got value for first time but I definitely get the value second time. `return [${ArrayPhone}, {Price: ${Price1}, Name: ${Name1}}]`

Comment: I didn't get the value at index 0 but at index 1 I got the value. *Strange?*

Comment: yes, this is strange. So I've updated my answer, because previous one was incorrect.